# Is ProClarity supported on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, proclarity

I'm currently in the process of coming up with our upgrade plan for our migration from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, and some of our business units still use ProClarity.

I'm aware that this is essentially a "dead" application; where Microsoft isn't upgrading it anymore, and it's scheduled to be EOL'ed in the future.

After googling and digging around on Microsoft's forums, I still can't come up with a definitive answer as to whether the 2012 upgrade will be incompatible with Proclarity. (Business users are on 6.2; which is one minor revision behind)

Has anybody tried this out and been successful?  Would we need to keep this portion of the BI tools on SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade was successful, and the users were able to connect to 2012 Analysis Services using ProClarity